# Accidentally screwed up permissions big time -- what should I do?

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm not very experienced with Linux and I made a big, big mistake. I ran the following command:

```
chown -R [ftpusername]:[ftpusername] /
```

I meant to run this:

```
chown -R [ftpusername]:[ftpusername] ./
```

See the problem?

I tried to correct my mistake by changing the owner of all files to `root`:

```
chown -R root:root /
```

Now I'm getting permissions errors when trying to access my websites, but my biggest concern is that I want to make sure I haven't caused any security vulnerabilities here.

Questions:

1. Was changing ownership of everything to `root` the right thing to do?
2. I think running `chown` caused some of the folder and file permissions to be changed. Is that normal? Would this cause any security vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Was changing ownership of everything to root the right thing to do?

**No**. It is, however, the quickest way I can think of to get the system to normal state.

- There are plenty of process which require some directories/files be owned by their user. Examples include logs, caches, working/home directories of some processes like MySQL, LightDM, etc. Especially log files can create a lot of problems.
- There are some applications which are `setuid`/`setgid`, and so need their owner/group to be something specific. Examples include `/usr/bin/at`, `/usr/bin/crontab`, etc.

> I think running chown caused some of the folder and file permissions to be changed. Is that normal?

<strike>I doubt modes got changed. If it did, it most definitely is not normal.</strike>

> Would this cause any security vulnerabilities?

<strike>Since you just set `/usr/bin/crontab` to be owned by `root`, you now have a setuid application that opens an editor. I doubt any vulnerabilities compare to that. Of course, this is a blatant vulnerability, so something more insidious might now pop up.</strike> Overall, I'd recommend simply re-installing the system - or hopefully you have full-disk backups.

Apparently, [`chown(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/chown) is supposed to clear the setuid and setgid bits if the running process doesn't have the appropriate privileges.  And [`man 2 chown`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chown) for Linux says:

> When the owner or group of an executable file are changed by an
>   unprivileged user the `S_ISUID` and `S_ISGID` mode bits are cleared.
>   POSIX does not specify whether this also should happen when root does
>   the `chown()`; the Linux behavior depends on the kernel version. In
>   case of a non-group-executable file (i.e., one for which the `S_IXGRP`
>   bit is not set) the `S_ISGID` bit indicates mandatory locking, and is
>   not cleared by a `chown()`.

So, it seems the devs and the standards committees have provided safegaurds.

Comment: on most systems, running chown will clear the suid and sgid bits.

Comment: @Joshua how do we know which systems? Any identifying characteristic?

Comment: Every system I've tried has the behavior including HP-UX, Linux, SunOS. If it weren't for the fact that the old SysV specs don't list it I would have been saying all systems.

Comment: @Joshua interesting. From [`man 3 chown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/chown.3posix.html): "If  the  specified  file is a regular file, one or more of the S_IXUSR, S_IXGRP, or S_IXOTH bits of the file mode are set, and the process does not  have  appropriate  privileges,  the set-user-ID (S_ISUID) and set-group-ID (S_ISGID)  bits  of  the  file  mode  shall  be  cleared   successful  return  from  chown()." (and a couple more lines on clearing suid and sgid bits) Any idea what these `S_IX*`  bits are and what the appropriate privileges are?

Comment: Those are the execute bits. The "appropriate privileges" is system specific (there is in fact no requirement that any specific privilege exists at all).

Comment: @Joshua updated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sister system or a backup? I.e. do you have a system from which you can copy the ownership?

If so: Copy the ownership and find the files that were not in the sister system and set the ownership on those manually.